# Onto map between the group algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, group-rings

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field of order $p$ ($p$ prime) and $G=SL(2,7)$ be a special linear group of $2\times 2$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{F_7}.$ Let $\mathbb{F}_pG$ be the group ring (or group algebra). Let $$\Phi: \mathbb{F}_pG\to M_4(\mathbb{F}_p)$$ be an algebra homomorphism. Here $M_4(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is the set of all $4\times 4$ matrices.

Let $\mathbb{F}_pG$ be semisimple. This means that $p\neq 2, 3, 7$. Then I want to know the values of $p$ for which $\Phi$ can be onto.

I know that if $p=11$, then $\Phi$ can be onto but if $p=17$, then $\Phi$ can not be onto.
How to show these? Is it related with the dimension of group algebra?

Please help me.

Comment: If F_pG is semisimple, then Wedderburn's theorem tells you that it is a direct product of matrix algebras over division algebras over F_p, and there will be a map from F_pG onto M_4(p) exactly when this last algebra is one of those direct factors. The proof of Wedderburn's theorem shows that this will happen exactly when G has a representation over F_p which appears four times in the regular representation whose endomorphism ring is F_p.